# firestore not working in netlify functions

Tags: firebase, netlify

```
module.exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {

const firebase=require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/firestore"); 

 

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: hidden,
  authDomain: hidden,
  projectId: hidden,
  storageBucket: hidden,
  messagingSenderId: hidden,
  appId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
let path = event.path.split('/').pop();
if(path==="hi"){
    return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `<h1 style="color:green;text-align:center">${path}</h1>`
    }
}
else{
    return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `<h1 style="color:green;text-align:center">${"contact site admin"}</h1>`
    }
}
    
}
```

the error is
**
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"firebase.firestore is not a function","trace":["TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function","    at Runtime.module.exports.handler (/var/task/server/index.js:22:21)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}
**